# NoClassDefFoundError error creating RestHighLevelClient bean

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch

I'm getting an error creating a HighEndRestClient bean in a SpringBoot app.  I have done a test 'app' where I checked I can instantiate the objects I want and then make the calls I want to and I am now making baby steps into making a new application.

I have these dependencies in the pom

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-client</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

and I have written this very basic code in a configuration class which doesn't do much yet

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:application.properties")
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "com.indexbuilder.es.repo")
public class ElasticsearchConfiguration {
    @Value("${elasticsearch.host}")
    private String EsHost;

    @Value("${elasticsearch.port}")
    private int EsPort;

    @Value("${elasticsearch.clustername}")
    private String EsClusterName;


    @Bean
    public RestClientBuilder coreBuilder() throws Exception {
        RestClientBuilder builder = RestClient.builder(new HttpHost("localhost", 9200, "http"));
        builder.setMaxRetryTimeoutMillis(10000);

        builder.setFailureListener(new RestClient.FailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(HttpHost host) {
                System.out.println("FAILURE !!!! FailureListener HAS WOKEN UP!!!! CREATYE A FAILURE LISTENER BEAN" );
            }
        });

        return builder;
      }

    @Bean
    public RestClient restLowLevelClient() throws Exception{
        RestClient restClient = coreBuilder().build();
        return restClient;
    }
```

This works fine as far as I can see (I haven't done much with it yet...)

when I add this (initially I was passing in the RestClient bean but now I'm temporarily creating a local object for more clarity)

```
    @Bean
    public RestHighLevelClient restHighLevelClient() throws Exception{
        RestClient restClient = coreBuilder().build();
        RestHighLevelClient client = new RestHighLevelClient(restClient);
        return client;
    }
```

I get this java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError error

> =========|_|==============|___/=/*/*/_/  :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.1.RELEASE)
>
> [WARNING]  java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:527)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'restHighLevelClient' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [com/indexbuilder/configuration/ElasticsearchConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient]: Factory
>   method 'restHighLevelClient' threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/elasticsearch/action/main/MainRequest     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:598)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1140)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1034)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:525)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:744)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151)
>     at
>   com.indexbuilder.SpringBootStartUpConfig.main(SpringBootStartUpConfig.java:84)
>     ... 6 more Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient]: Factory
>   method 'restHighLevelClient' threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/elasticsearch/action/main/MainRequest     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:587)
>     ... 24 more Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/elasticsearch/action/main/MainRequest     at
>   com.indexbuilder.configuration.ElasticsearchConfiguration.restHighLevelClient(ElasticsearchConfiguration.java:95)
>     at
>   com.indexbuilder.configuration.ElasticsearchConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$62f74d9a.CGLIB$restHighLevelClient$1()
>     at
>   com.indexbuilder.configuration.ElasticsearchConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$62f74d9a$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$2b29ad7b.invoke()
>     at
>   org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358)
>     at
>   com.indexbuilder.configuration.ElasticsearchConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$62f74d9a.restHighLevelClient()
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
>     ... 25 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.elasticsearch.action.main.MainRequest     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     ... 36 more

Can anyone point me in the right direction ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You probably need the core dependency as well:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>5.6.3</version>
</dependency>
```

A `NoClassDefFoundError` is generally a configuration error - it means that the code you use references a certain class, but the class itself isn't in the classpath. In this case, this might also be a dependency management error in the relevant Elasticsearch poms themselves, as they should include the needed classes - but there's not much you can do about that other than perhaps file an issue.

Comment: I had the same problem. For some reason spring boot has a managed elasticsearch 2.x dependency.

Comment: Perfect.. Thanks!!

Comment: Note: The version should be the same between all the dependencies, I got the same error for version mismatch.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.
ElasticSearch pointed to old version:

```
org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:6.2.3 -> 1.5.2
```

I used dependencyManagement gradle plugin to force use the version I mention:

```
dependencyManagement {
dependencies {
    dependency 'org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:6.2.3'
}}
```

For more info: https://github.com/spring-gradle-plugins/dependency-management-plugin